# imwrite does not create image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
const char* imageName = "samp.png";

Mat image;
image = imread( imageName, 1 );


Mat gray_image;
cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );

imwrite( "/home/Downloads/Pictures/Gray_Image.jpg",gray_image );



namedWindow( imageName, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
namedWindow( "Gray image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );



imshow( imageName, image );
imshow( "Gray image", gray_image );

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

'imwrite" in the above code does not create image.Everything else works fine,and I can see the image using imshow.But I dont know why it is not creating a image.I tried 'convertTo' and replacing '/' to '\' in the path, but it does not work.I will be pleased if I get any lead.Thanks!

Comment: your path: "/home/.../.../Gray_Image.jpg" looks murky. first, there's no such thing as `/.../` did you mean `/../` ? and then, `/home` is a toplevel folder already, you can't go up 2 times from there

Comment: I was just trying to say some directories are there in between, Ex: "/home/Downloads/Pictures/Gray-Image.jpg" Sorry for the ambiguity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not documented clearly, but `imwrite` returns a boolean which is `true` if and only if it thinks that it could write the file successfully. You should check that value!

You'll probably find out that `imwrite` returns `false`. Most likely you do not have sufficient permissions or -- as berak pointed out -- your file path is invalid.

By the way, for proper error handling, you should also catch exceptions, in particular, if the user provides the output file URL. If OpenCV, for some reason, can't find a suitable encoder (i.e. it can't recognize which type of file you are going to write), it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Markus Mayr's response helped me find out that I was getting a false when I printed the result of imwrite. The reason turned out to be, the directory in which I was trying to write, didnt exist. I was assuming it will create the directory but imwrite silently failed.After I manually created the directory it worked